# Background colour not displaying properly with text and image

Tags: html, css

At https://www.artisanbelle.com I have testimonials with photo and text displayed next to them (scroll down midway). I would like the grey background to only be on the text. I tried doing that, adding it to the text divs, but it didn't work. So I added it to the container div (pic-testimonial) that contains the image as well, but now it is showing up around the image, and I don't want it outside the image at all. I am not sure how to fix this.

```css
.testimonial-container {
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
}


/* For mobile */

.testimonial-imga,
.testimonial-imgb,
.testimonial-texta,
.testimonial-textb {
  width: 100%;
}

.testimonial-imga,
.testimonial-imgb {
  float: left;
}

.testimonial-texta,
.testimonial-textb {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.pic-testimonial::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.testimonial-photo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 451px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* for desktop */
  .pic-testimonial {
    background-color: #DFE3E6;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .testimonial-imga,
  .testimonial-texta,
  .testimonial-imgb,
  .testimonial-textb {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .testimonial-imga {
    float: left;
  }
  .testimonial-imgb {
    float: right;
  }
  .testimonial-texta {
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 50% background-color: #DFE3E6;
  }
  .testimonial-textb {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 50%
  }
  .photo1 {
    display: block;
    height: 451px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  .testimonial-photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .test-text,
  .test-text2 {
    position: relative;
  }
  .test-text p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-16%, 80%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  .test-text2 p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-16%, 15%);
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.testimonial-texta p {
  color: #235A4A;
}

.testimonial-textb p {
  color: #235A4A;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-container">

  <div class="pic-testimonial">
    <div class="testimonial-imga">
      <figure class="photo1"><img class="testimonial-photo" src="http://www.artisanbelle.com/images/stories/amandac.jpg" alt="Amanda C"></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-texta">
      <div class="test-text">
        <p>"These white topaz earrings are gorgeous. The stones catch the light and are so pretty. They can be dressed up or down and the craftsmanship is top quality. A great pair of earrings that go with everything." <br>- Amanda Coldwell</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  // more pic-testimonial blocks

</div>
```

I would like the grey background only around the entire text block next to the picture, not around the image. I would like it to extend from the right side of the image all the way to the entire block of text.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `background-color` from .pic-testimonial class. and

Add bellow CSS:

```
.pic-testimonial {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.testimonial-texta {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #DFE3E6;
}
```

You missed `;` after width property in `.testimonial-texta`. I have correct it

Comment: That is better. How do I add the background to the right side of the div containing the image though? I wanted it to extend all the way across from the right side of the picture.

Comment: You need to add background-color css for .testimonial-texta and .testimonial-textb both OR you can add common class for both and apply css to it

Comment: I did add the background colour to testimonial-texta as you described and its filled that div box. But the image is centred in the other div box and that's why there is space on the right of it. I'm not sure how to make that the same background colour. I don't want the whole div of the image to be background colour, just on the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

first you remove the background-color in '.pic-testimonial' class and add the background color in '.test-text p' class you got the answer.